# Unable to start the Gateway from the wso2apim-gateway-3.0.0 root directory by using "bin/ballerina run service services.bsz"

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, ballerina

I have build the wso2apimanager source code successfully in eclipse using maven and got the following zip file.

1. wso2apim-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
2. wso2apim-das-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
3. wso2apim-gateway-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

To run the wso2apim, i have run the following file.

```
1.Start ActiveMQ using ./bin/activemq start

2.execute the worker.bat script from the wso2apim-das-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/bin directory

3.execute the carbon.bat script from the wso2apim-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/wso2/key-manager/bin directory

4.execute the carbon.bat script from the wso2apim-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/wso2/default//bin directory


5.When I am execute the "bin/ballerina run service services.bsz" command in the wso2apim-gateway-3.0.0-SNAPSHOT directory. IT is not execute and given error as below
```

**The input line is too long.

The syntax of command is incorrect**.

I have already installed the "ballerina-tools-0.95.6" tool and set the path of ballerina in environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APIM gateway does not support ballerina latest version. Could you download ballerina 0.89 version [1] and try?

[1] https://github.com/ballerinalang/ballerina/releases/tag/v0.89